# Mongoose find() returning only one document in production, works normally in development

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a simple query in mongoose:

```
var emails = [];
User.find({ subscribed: true })
.exec(function(err, users) {
    console.log(users)
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }

    async.forEach(users, function(user, callback) {
        if (emails.indexOf(user.email) == -1) {
            console.log(user.email)
            emails.push(user.email)
            send(post, user.email)
            callback()                  
        }
    })
})
```

There are 3 Users. When I run this query, only one is ever returned and it's always the same User. When I replace the line `User.find({ subscribed: true })` with `User.find({})`, all accounts are returned, however when the User are printed in the console they all clearly show `subscribed: true`.

Additionally, the query executes as expected on my local development environment. The issue only occurs on my production server. Could this be a mongo/mongoose/Node version issue?

Comment: can you copy your user data from production and post it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var emails = [];
User.find({ subscribed: true },(function(err, users) {
    console.log(users)
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    }  
    async.forEach(users, function(user, callback) {
        if (emails.indexOf(user.email) == -1) {
            console.log(user.email)
            emails.push(user.email)
            send(post, user.email)
            callback()                  
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Thanks but still same result

Comment: Try lodash foreach instead of async may help

Comment: and what is the output for console.log(users)

Comment: I have already tried lodash actually, still same result. For now I'm just returning all users and filtering them with subscribed === true